# return false on jQuery AJAX's beforeSend - $.ajaxError is called

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
function load() {
            var url = buildUrl(null, true);
            $.ajax(url, {
                cache: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    if (typeof plugin.cache[url] !== 'undefined') {
                        var result = plugin.cache[url];
//                        xhr.done();
//                        xhr.abort();
//                        xhr.complete();
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;

                },
                success: function(result, textStatus, jqXHR ) {


                    handleResult(result);

                    plugin.cache[url] = JSON.stringify(result);
                }
            });

        };




$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
switch (jqxhr.status) { 
  ..
  }
}
```

When I have the result cached, I'd like `$.ajax` not to proceed with the call. 
If I return false or call `xhr.abort()` from `beforeSend()`, ajaxError is triggered. When I call `xhr.done()` or `xhr.complete()`, the call proceeds.

Is there any way I can stop the call from proceeding without triggering `$.ajaxError`?

Comment: The browser will serve cached results automatically, is there a specific reason you want to avoid doing this?

Comment: For some reason, setting the cache property to true (only), still makes an AJAX request.

Comment: Cache only works with GET and HEAD requests if you are not using these you need to implement the cache manually - something that you are already doing. So in order to prevent the error call you need to check the manual cache before you make the ajax request.

Comment: By default, $.ajax uses the GET method. isn't that true?

Comment: What do you mean by checking the manual cache ? I am checking whether the URL exists as a key...

Comment: Yes the GET method is default, is the server returning the correct cache headers?

Comment: If it's a server issue, I'd rather do manual caching, without triggering ajaxError

Comment: I have provided a code sample as an answer, the handleResult() function may need to be moved depending on what it does since I was not sure whether it's meant to handle the raw response data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the test for weather you need to make the ajax call like this:

```
function load() {
    var url = buildUrl(null, true);
    if (typeof plugin.cache[url] === 'undefined') 
    {
        $.ajax(url, {
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                plugin.cache[url] = JSON.stringify(result);
            }
        });
    }
    handleResult(plugin.cache[url]);
};
```

Comment: I should take a glance outside the box more often :) thank you Vishal.